# What permissions do you need to take a mysql database backup via SSH?

Tags: mysql, backup

are 'SELECT' and 'LOCK' privileges enough for a 'mysql database user' to take a full database backup via SSH? I am able to take a backup using these privileges, but unsure if I am backing up all the files properly. So my question is, are these two privileges enough or does the user need more privileges in order to take a proper backup?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the options you use with the dump you may need more (or less). The one you definitely need is **SELECT**.

- If you use triggers you need **TRIGGER**
- If you use views you need **SHOW VIEW**
- If you don't use --single-transaction in the dump you will need **LOCK TABLES**

For more info on the subject you can go to: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html